# Save FileDialog output for later processing

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code that does several manipulations on files, then prints and export to PDF.

I'm trying to create a GUI (userform) so others can use this code.

To reorganize the code to assign the correct trigger (button click), I need to "store" the files selected on the dialog into a string (maybe not ideal?), so that they can be accessed by another sub.

Part of the code, to be put in a separate sub, making it possible to assign a trigger.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public fldr As FileDialog, PastaSalvar As String, fileName As Variant, Formulário As Worksheet, total As Integer, NomeArq As String, WB As String, fDialog As FileDialog, directory As String, WBExt As String

Sub Certificado()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Call GetFolder

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)  ' **
With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Selecionar os Arquivos"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Todos os Arquivos Suportados", "*.xls;*.xlsx"
    If .Show = True Then**
        For Each fileName In .SelectedItems
            directory = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "\"))
            Workbooks.Open (fileName)
            Worksheets("CERTIFICADO").Activate

            Call Altera
            Call PDF
            Call Imprime
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Next
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

---

HackSlash shed some light on the matter but I wasn't clear on my issue.

It is not the entire section of code that I need, only the part below, which is already implemented with HackSlash's suggestion.

```vb
Function SelArq() As Collection
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Selecionar os Arquivos"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Todos os Arquivos Suportados", "*.xls;*.xlsx"
        If .Show = True Then
            SelArq() = .SelectedItems
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

It is the result of that selection that I need to show on a textbox and use as argument for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

`.SelectedItems` returns a collection so you need to capture it in a collection variable.

I will recommend that you only use global variables when absolutely necessary. I changed Certificado in to a function so that it can return the result of the dialog. Wherever you are using the result you would capture it by capturing the return from Certificado.

Like `fileList = Certificado`

EXAMPLE:

```
Option Explicit

Function Certificado() As Collection
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim PastaSalvar As String
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim Formulário As Worksheet
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim NomeArq As String
    Dim WB As String
    Dim directory As String
    Dim WBExt As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    GetFolder

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Selecionar os Arquivos"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Todos os Arquivos Suportados", "*.xls;*.xlsx"
        If .Show = True Then
            Certificado = .SelectedItems
            For Each fileName In Certificado
                Dim certWorkbook As Workbook
                directory = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "\"))
                Set certWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
                certWorkbook.Worksheets("CERTIFICADO").Activate
    
                Altera
                PDF
                Imprime
                certWorkbook.Close
            Next
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Comment: @RogerRangel This is not a forum or a discussion. The Q&A format is one question, one answer. If you have a new question please close this question, by marking my answer with the green checkmark and ask a new question. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask